# Decorator error upon registrating command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a general purpose discord bot, and when executing the following code:

```
@client.command()
async def help(ctx):
  embed=discord.Embed(title="Here are all the current commands!")
  embed.add_field(name="Help", value="You're here!", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="8ball", value="Have a question? A doubt? Ask the magic 8ball!", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="Clear", value="Clear the last 10 messages, without exception of user or content. ", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="Ping", value="Run a ping test!", inline=True)
  embed.set_footer(text="Thanks for using JARGPDB! (Just Another Regular General Purpose Discord Bot)")
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
client.run('token')
```

I get the following set of errors:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "main.py", line 51, in <module>
        async def help(ctx):
      File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1263, in decorator
        self.add_command(result)
      File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1149, in add_command
        raise CommandRegistration
```

Comment: Usually a decorator will be used like `@client.command` i.e. without the `()`

Comment: check the different command, as it seems two commands have same name [CommandRegistration](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commandregistration#discord.ext.commands.CommandRegistrationError)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion decorator shouldn't have `()`.

```
@client.command
async def help(ctx):
  embed=discord.Embed(title="Here are all the current commands!")
  embed.add_field(name="Help", value="You're here!", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="8ball", value="Have a question? A doubt? Ask the magic 8ball!", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="Clear", value="Clear the last 10 messages, without exception of user or content. ", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="Ping", value="Run a ping test!", inline=True)
  embed.set_footer(text="Thanks for using JARGPDB! (Just Another Regular General Purpose Discord Bot)")
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
client.run('token')
```